# I want to replay an action on a website

Tags: macros, web, imacros

I need to get one course on the university website.
However the enrollment is full and I can only get a seat if some other student drops this course.

I do not know the time when He/She will drop this course.
So I have to sit on this website for a whole day and click the enroll button until someone actually drops this course.

I have to make a software through node JS which can do this task for me at an interval of 5 seconds.

I am asking if there is an already available tool that I can use for this task.

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementById("BUTTON_ID").click();
}, 5000)
```

This functions simulates clicks at every 5 seconds. Replace BUTTON_ID with the enroll button's id, press F12 and try running this code in browser's console.
I've tested it on Firefox.

Comment: So the web browser goes to a new page after the "enroll" button click and returns back after click on another button "return"

Comment: This implies more information about the 'return' button in order to perform a good '

Comment: ....'wait until ready' function. However I would stick to the same function and replace BUTTON_ID with 'return's'. And instead of 5000 I would raise up to 15000 (to make sure the whole page is loaded up.